# Error is asynctask onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need some help here! In my asyncTask i am adding values to ArrayList Result and when i try to fetch the result value in onPostExecute by

```
final String output = result.get(0);
```

The app is force closing. I know it may be a silly mistake. But i am not understanding why!

```
public class deviceVerify extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            progress1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... passing) {
            // Locate the WorldhavingDelay Class
            // JSON file URL address
            final ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
            String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            try {
                Log.e("URL",Constants.BASE_URL_LOGIN+"?deviceid="+android_id);
                RestClientHelper.getInstance().get(Constants.BASE_URL_LOGIN+"?deviceid="+android_id, new RestClientHelper.RestClientListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String response) {
                        Log.e("Resposnse",response);
                        result.add("true");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(String error) {
                        Log.e("Error",error);
                        result.add("false");
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                result.add("false");
            }
            return result;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<String> result) {
            final String output = result.get(0);
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progress1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    if(output.equals("true")){
                        TextView verifytext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.verifytext);
                        verifytext.setText("Device Verified");
                        ImageView error = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.messageImage);
                        error.setImageResource(DeviceVerification.this.getResources().getIdentifier("check", "drawable", DeviceVerification.this.getPackageName()));
                    }
                    else{
                        TextView verifytext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.verifytext);
                        verifytext.setText("An Error Occured on verifying device!");
                        ImageView error = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.messageImage);
                        error.setImageResource(DeviceVerification.this.getResources().getIdentifier("warning", "drawable", DeviceVerification.this.getPackageName()));
                        Button tryagain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trygain);
                        tryagain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                }
            }, 10000);
        }
```

LOG ERROR:

```
02-22 15:06:34.708 10664-10664/in.juasoft.mobeeload E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: in.juasoft.mobeeload, PID: 10664
                                                                      java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                                                                          at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                          at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                          at in.juasoft.mobeeload.DeviceVerification$deviceVerify.onPostExecute(DeviceVerification.java:110)
                                                                          at in.juasoft.mobeeload.DeviceVerification$deviceVerify.onPostExecute(DeviceVerification.java:78)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5037)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: final String output = result.get(0).toString(); try this

Comment: Do all stuff of onPostExcecute in OnSuceess method

Comment: Why accepting the result as string?

Comment: i think you are getting empty arraylist.so arrayoutofbound exception

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<String> result) please debug and check here is result contains something or not?

Comment: @ZakiPathan  result.get(0).toString(); didnt work

Comment: @KarthikCP please debug and check protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<String> result) here result got something or not?

Comment: Let be check...

Comment: your result size is zero

Comment: @ZakiPathan.. Yeah why? In background task it is logging the response in onSuccessm method there i am adding to result! So it should be in result list right?

Comment: Are you sure you need that in an `AsyncTask`? It would seem that `RestClientHelper` is already asynchronous, which would explain your problem. That's why it has the `RestClientListener`; to call back when it's done.

Comment: put a check to get the size of result before fetching the index 0 item.

Comment: @MikeM. Yeah Let me try that by removing asyncTask

Comment: your debugger goes in onSuccess method and add value in result result.add("true");? or result.add never executes?

Comment: I can't understand why you're creating ArrayList for 1 value...

Comment: @VygintasB No. There are more values to come! i am just cecking it with one value as of now

Comment: @MikeM. Yeah removed asyncTask and now its okay!!

Answer (score 1):

**change**

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>;
//remove final from result
```

also change it not require but only for standar codding

```
if(result != null && result.size()>0){   
      final String output = result.get(0);
    }
```

change on onpost method 
You are gettting this error because u get result size zero

Answer (score 1):

You are adding data in ArrayList **"result"** on "onSuccess" method which is callback method.. but before onSuccess get executed onPostExcecute method get called at that time ArrayList **"result**" is empty thats why IndexOutOfBoundExeption ouccured.

Comment: Yeah i think so!! Let me avoid asynTask and check

Comment: put your all code of onPostExcecute method on "onSuccess" method.. and remove AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

I think your try to modify the final variable here `result.add("true");` and here `result.add("false");`